# Filter non-alpha-numeric and make titlecase

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list with a bunch of names which I need to turn into alphanumeric usernames. What I would like to do is take the name, remove any non-alpha numeric values and turn it into title case where characters were removed. For example:

```
 johnson -> Johnson
 Van Halen -> VanHalen
 Torres-hernandez -> TorresHernandez
 Rafael van der vaart -> RafaelVanDerVaart
```

Can this be done with a regular expression?

Comment: Which regular expression do you use?

Comment: First what have you tried ? Second it's utterly **important** to know which flavor/language you're using.

Comment: Apologies. I'm using this in the browser (javascript)

Comment: Hmmm I hope you're also aware that there are some names which don't follow this logic. Take for example [`Rafael van der Vaart`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rafael_van_der_Vaart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using some string manipulation, you can do this fairly simply.

```
var name = "Torres-hernandez", i, part, out = "";
parts = name.split(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi);
for (i=0; part = parts[i++];) {
    out += part[0].toUpperCase() + part.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var names = [
    'johnson',
    'Van Halen',
    'Torres-hernandez',
    'Rafael van der vaart'
]

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    names[i] = names[i].replace(/(\W|^)(\w)/g, function(match) {
        return match.substr(-1).toUpperCase();
    });
}
console.log(names);
```

prints

```
[ 'Johnson', 'VanHalen', 'TorresHernandez', 'RafaelVanDerVaart' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple regexp:

```
var titleCase = function(s) {
  return s.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\W)+(\w|$)/g, function(match, tail) {
    return tail.toUpperCase();
  });
};
```

Regular expression `/(?:^|\W)+(\w|$)/g` here catches substrings from the begining of the previous word to the first letter of the new one which should be capitalized.

It captures the whole match and replaces it with the uppercased last character `tail`.

If your string ends with bad characters (e.g. whitespaces) then it'll be captured too, but `taild` in this case will be an empty string:

```
'   toRReS $#@%^! heRnAndeZ -++--=-=' -> 'TorresHernandez'
```

Let's examine my regexp:

- `(^|\W)+` - the sequence `(...)+` of non-alphanumeric characters `\W` or the start of the string `^` which may be followed by any number of non-alphanumeric characters. It should contain at leas one character unless it's the start of the string, it which case it may be empty.
- `(?:^|\W)+` - same thing, but it won't be cached because of `?:`. We don't really care about this part and just want to strip it.
- `(\w|$)` - any alphanumeric characters `\w` or the end of the string `$`. This part will be cached and placed into `tail` variable.

**Update** If regular expressions confuses you, you may do the same thing with string and array operations:

```
var titleCase = function(str) {
  return str.split(/\W+/g)
    .filter(function(s) {
      return s.length > 0;
    }).map(function(s) {
      return s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }).join('');
};
```

This solution was inspired by [FakeRainBrigand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098062/filter-non-alpha-numeric-and-make-titlecase/18098232#18098232) and is very similar to his own. The difference is that my version uses array operations instead of `for` loop and uses `filter` to handle strings with bad character at the beginning or at the and of it.

I used `\w` and `\W` special literals in my regular expressions which are equal to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and `[^A-Za-z0-9_]` respectively ([see JavaScript Regular Expressions Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters)). If you don't want `_` to be counted as an alphanumeric character you should replace `\w` and `\W` with exact character sets to be matched (e.g. `[A-Za-z0-9]` and `[^A-Za-z0-9]`).